# При нажатии на инлайн кнопку выводится много сообщенйий

Tags: python, sql, aiogram

помогите, пожалуйста. Сделал колбэк хэндлер, который выводит инлайн кнопки вкуса модели, но при нажатии на кнопку модели, выводится много сообщений.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код колбэк хэндера (смысл верхнего хэндлера ещё в том, чтобы при пополнении товара, не создавалась кнопка бренд если такая уже есть):

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('brand_'))
async def choose_model(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    brang = callback_query.data.split('_')[1]
    models = db.cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT model FROM items WHERE brang = ?', (brang,)).fetchall()
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    buttons = [InlineKeyboardButton(text=row[0], callback_data=f"model_{row[0]}") for row in models
               if not any(row[0] in button.text for button in markup.inline_keyboard)]
    # Если список кнопок не пустой, создаем разметку клавиатуры и отправляем сообщение пользователю
    if buttons:
        markup = markup.add(*buttons)
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Выберите модель", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "неу брендов")


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('model_'))
async def show_item(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    model = callback_query.data.split('_')[1]
    items = [row[0] for row in db.cur.execute('SELECT taste FROM items WHERE model = ?', (model,)).fetchall()]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    for taste in items:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=taste, callback_data=f"model_{taste}"))
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"Выберите вкус модели {model}", reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: У вас send_message внутри цикла — значит логично, что отправится ровно столько сообщений, сколько итераций в цикле

Answer (score -1):

[image]

просто поставь отправляемое сообщение на одном уровне что и for

Comment: Код нужно добавлять текстом, а не скриншотом. [Почему не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)